# Drawing a line on transparent qt widget

Tags: qt, qpainter

I want to achieve this :

1. Have a transparent surface of some width and height (A transparent widget)
2. Draw something on this surface such that only outlines of that figure are visible on the screen and nothing else (no background of the surface on which I am drawing should be there)

I made a widget and achieved to make it transparent like this :

```
window.setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
window.setWindowFlags (Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
window.setGeometry( 0,0,1200, 800 );
window.show();
```

Then I overrode the function paintEvent(QPaintEvent *); to make a ellipse using QPainter.

But still the surface is coming to be black color only. Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to what I did in a similar app, but I also did:

```
window.setAutoFillBackground(false);
```

Perhaps that's the missing piece for you?

**Edit:** Another idea: In your `paintEvent`, do you fill the widget `rect()` with a fully transparent color before you paint the ellipse?

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I had tried that also actually, but of no use, still a black background.

Comment: Holy smoke! it started working.. Unfortunately I had deleted the code which i tried yesterday so cant say what made it work, but yes it is working now. Perhaps as you said, I might have been drawing a rectangle and filling it. Now I am doing just drawing ellipse directly 
    painter.drawEllipse(rectangle); Thanks.